# how to add xml declaration to the intellij xml output

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

Bear with me... i have no idea of coding and i am trying to add few things to the existing code. The code has no errors, however, the output misses the xml declaration.

The message i get is,
*This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.*

Current output

```
- <List xmlns="">
- <item>
  <Project_name>just like that</Project_name> 
  </item>
...
```

Expected output

```
- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
- <item>
  <Project_name>just like that</Project_name> 
  </item>
...
```

I am using Intellij, java.

The line which produces the current output is here

```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/testproject",method = RequestMethod.GET produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) // to get xml output
```

I know this is very less information, but to confidentiality i cannot add more code

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In order to marshal your response into XML format, a corresponding schema has to exist. Usually this can be done using [JAXB annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) in the classes that you want to send in your xml response. A plain example is the one below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody MyList get(){
        MyList list = new MyList(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
            add(2);
            add(3);
            add(4);
        }});

        return list;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "MyList")
class MyList{
    List<Integer> list;

    public MyList() {
    }

    public MyList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

This will produce the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <MyList>
            <list>2</list>
            <list>3</list>
            <list>4</list>
        </MyList>
```

You need to add the `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` annotation to the class that you want to send in XML format.